# Writing to a file whenever you want and not in exact async sequence

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, file-io

I can write to a file using examples provided on Phonegap docs [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileWriter). However you must respect file system async calls:

1. requesting file system (inside device ready event)
2. getting/creating file (success callback of line 1)
3. creating file writer (success callback of line 2)
4. writing to a file (success callback of line 3)

**Question:** How can I write to my file somewhere else in my code and not inside the success callback of the third line above?

I would need to get writer object somehow and I found no other easy solution (i could probably timeout and wait for a writer object to become available, make it global and use it later but that doesn't seem quite nice)

Here's the code from Phonegap site that shows all the necessary steps to write to a file:

```
// Wait for device API libraries to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
}

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile("readme.txt", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
}

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
}

function gotFileWriter(writer) {
    writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
        console.log("contents of file now 'some sample text'");
        writer.truncate(11);
        writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
            console.log("contents of file now 'some sample'");
            writer.seek(4);
            writer.write(" different text");
            writer.onwriteend = function(evt){
                console.log("contents of file now 'some different text'");
            }
        };
    };
    writer.write("some sample text");
}

function fail(error) {
    console.log(error.code);
}
```

Comment: Seriously that is the example from Phonegap site? An event-handler  within an event-handler for the same event? *shakes head*

Comment: @supertopi yes, that is a copy-paste code from the Full Example on the link I provided.

Comment: you can create your own global module/object during the start of your application ( eg. var myAppGlobalModue = { writerobj:"} and then initialize "myAppGlobalModue.writerobj = writer" property at the above success callback. Anyway you would have to store the handle somewhere for use.

Comment: @frank only doing window.myWriter = writer wouldn't just work huh?So I could use window.myWriter later

Comment: In your `function gotFileWriter(writer) {myAppGlobalModue.writerobj = writer }` you can initialize the writerobj and then use it whereever you want. If you want a global variable in the window object `function gotFileWriter(writer) {window.myWriter = writer }`

Comment: This actually seems to work now that I refactored my app. All that async behaviour makes it hard to figure out what happened when if you don't follow the exact one-after-another sequence.

Comment: @trainoasis can you put your solution over here, So that it may be useful to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up saving writer object to window variable to make it global and then I waited for the writer to become defined when I needed it (pretty ugly solution, I know, but I needed to use it like this to get it working with the app I got from the previous guy :D)

```
function gotFileWriter(writer) {  
    window.myWriter = writer;       
}
```

When the string that you want to write to your file becomes available:

```
while(window.myWriter === undefined){
    //some exit condition or timer to break based on your previous code 
}
window.myWriter.write("Your string to write to your file")
```

In my case window.myWriter was available instantaneously, but please don't use while(true) kind of loop without some thoughtful exit condition.